# Reading text file, apostrophe displayed as \325

Tags: c++, file-io, text-files

I searched for a similar thread, but I could not find one (probably searching the wrong terminology). But I'm trying to read from a text file, one word at a time, and words like It's is replaced with It\325s and using quotes like "Hello" is replaced with \322Hello\323. It seems this is something trivial but I haven't found anything to solve it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Note: this is a personal project, not a class assignment

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

ifstream document ("filename.txt");
string word;

while (document >> word)
{
    cout << word << endl;
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: The text file may have a different encoding than you expect? Open it in a good text-editor and it might be able to autodetect the encoding.

Comment: You can convert a file encoding using iconv.  Just `man iconv` for explanation.  If you are on Windows, you may have to download the utility.

Comment: Could these be so-called ['smart quotes'](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html) (ugh)?

Comment: Your document is probably encoded in UTF. Try running `file filename.txt` and see if it can tell you the encoding.

Answer (score -1):

If the text had been written with a word processor chances are that characters like `'` and `"` are replace with the corresponding "*english*" open and close ones.

In certain encodings, they are encoded with bytes of value grated than 127.
\322 \323 and \325 (you didn't specify how id you know them) watching the string into a debugger?) are just the octal representation of character the program you are using to visualize them (Is it a debug variable watcher?) doesn't want to print since are not plain ASCII (hence code-page dependent).

Instead ow watch the string with a debugger, try to print it out.